# Ubuntu 13.10 boots into blank screen after grub

Tags: boot, 13.10, grub2

Recently after force shutting down during a long Shutdown then when it started up it would go to grub and then it would flash a login screen before going black with a not moving terminal cursor. After searching for a result I saw a solution to a similar problem which was to change the boot code in grub from quiet splash to Nomodset and when I tried that it worked for a while but now I have to constantly change the boot code and its a random chance if it works, no pattern showing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you must boot your Ubuntu from a live cd or a live USB stick and choose the option `Try Ubuntu`.
open a terminal and type( or just copy paste) this following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

hit ENTER

then type this command also

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

after installing boot repair choose recommended repair.

then reboot your computer and all must work  like charm.