# Ubuntu 14.04.4 - Screen is blank with blinking cursor

Tags: nvidia, xorg, screen

Well now, when trying to force Hatari onto a particular screen, in the process deleting xorg.conf, I seem to have broken everything.

Now when I try to boot into Ubuntu 14.04.4, everything seems to boot ok, masses of text go by, and then it just sits there with a black screen and a blinking line. I cannot `Ctrl + Alt` into any of the `tty`s, nothing gets typed when I press keys, and none of the special keys like the `shutdown key` work. The only thing that responds is the `power button` which starts the `unattended updates` and then the final shutdown sequence.

I've tried many things short of formatting and reinstalling `sda1`, simply because I have many repositories and programs installed, and I wish to keep the Classic Gnome session for my login. Unless you know of a way to keep all that (`synaptic`) information somewhere and once restored will automatically install what's missing?

The things I've tried:

- Replaced `xorg.conf` with one of the backups and `.failsafe`
- Removed `~/.config/monitors.xml`
- Tried generating a new `xorg.conf` with `sudo X -configure` through LiveCD giving the error:

  `No devices to configure. Configuration failed.
  (EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.`
- Installed `boot-repair` and tried to run it through LiveCD's terminal [(using the following)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446157/ubuntu-13-10-boots-into-blank-screen-after-grub), but nothing seems to have happened. Something about Gtk errors.
- Reinstalled `xserver-xorg` from LiveCD using `chroot` into `sda1`
- My options in the `recovery mode` are:
  [recover mode options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Jh0.png)

  - `dpkg` - Runs for a bit with remounting the file systems, then does nothing for an hour. By pressing `Ctrl + C` it ends and resumes normal boot, up to the blank screen.
  - `fsck` - Seems to run, passing through the basic volumes, then doesn't seem to do anything. I've monitored my drive LED but it seems to just stop. By pressing `Ctrl + C` after a long wait of nothing, it ends and resumes normal boot, up to the blank screen.
  - `network` - Runs for a bit with remounting the file systems, then does nothing for an hour. By pressing `Ctrl + C` it ends and resumes normal boot, up to the blank screen.
  - `root` - Here I am able to move and copy files around, but `X` or `Xorg`, `apt-get`, `dpkg` or anything of that nature doesn't seem to exist.

So, short of reinstalling everything, what else can I try (be specific where to try it, like LiveCD terminal, `chroot`ed, or `recovery mode`)?

NOTE that I can't seem to run the LiveCD's Desktop through "Try Ubuntu". I get a black screen with the mouse, and if I wait long enough it would seem the keyboard stops working (can't get into any `tty`s).

Comment: Try sudo rm .Xauthority

Answer (score 0):

Well, by some miracle after doing another reinstall and dpkg-reconfigure of xserver-xorg, all is back to normal now.